# Plotting pre aggregated data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have pre-calculated data with amount on the x axis and the count (as a proportion) which I'm using as the y axis.

What I would like to have is the functionality I would get if I had used stat="bin". I can't use rep to simply explode the data to it's original form and then rebin it, because of the large size of the dataset.

For example:
I would like to be able to smooth the data, like I would have been able to by using binwidth.

Also, I'm plotting this data using geom_freqpoly. However, if I don't have a specific amount on the x axis I'd like to have it as a 0 value, instead of joining to the next point, which binning using ggplot does.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one had a response for ggplot, I used rep to re-expand and sample the data.

So, if I had 18 million observations originally, I used 180,000 for the times argument of rep, and multiplied by this by my previously calculated proportion of the data. I'm not sure what the threshold would then be for the times argument (if it's less than 1 will no data point be created?). This means I lose the less frequent observations altogether, but this is OK in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the `ggplot` stat functions will accept a weight as part of the aesthetic, e.g.:  `aex(x=X, y=Y, weight=n)`.  Depending on you versions, a couple even complain about the "unused aesthetic, 'weight'", but then go on to do the right thing!  I've used this on `geom_hist`, `bin2d`, and probably others.